# Is the $2$-norm a lower bound for the dual norm?

Tags: inequality, normed-spaces

From *Convex Optimization* by Boyd & Vandengergh:

> Let $||\cdot\|$ be any norm. Then $\|x\|_* \ge \gamma \|x\|_2$ for some $\gamma \in (0,1] $.

I start by assuming that $\gamma \gt 1$. Then

$$\gamma \|e_i\|_2 = \gamma \cdot 1 = \gamma \le \sup \{e^Tz : \|z\| \le 1\} = \sup \{z_i : \|z\| \le 1\}$$

where $e_i = \langle0, \dots, 0, 1, 0 , \dots, 0\rangle$, i.e., a single $1$ at position $i$ and $0$ everywhere else. From here I am having trouble showing a contradiction.  Is there a simple next step or is there a completely easier way to show this?

Comment: This is not true on the space $c_{00}$, for example.

Comment: Usually you just define $γ=\inf_{\|x\|_2=1}\|x\|_*$ and use that all norms are continuous functions, or in stronger words, define all the same topology. Of course that pre-supposes that the space is finite-dimensional.